# SQL multiple orderby for table columns

Tags: mysql

in one of my table on SQL i'm trying use priority `orderBy` to sort data for output for example

```
select * from user ORDER BY 
     (CASE 
        WHEN role = 1  THEN ???
      END),
    CASE 
        WHEN permission = 2  THEN ???
        WHEN access = 3 ??
    END)
```

i just learn about this command to get result and making priority `orderBy`, how can i fix this command to get correct result?

first ordering by role, second ordering by permission and third ordering by access to get single result on output

```
select * from user ORDER BY 
->(if role = 1 )
->(or permission = 2 )
->(or access = 3 )
```

Comment: Add an example so we know what you want. Your code does not make sense

Comment: @juergend my post updated, please review that, thanks

Comment: So do you mean, 'if role = 1 Order By role?' and so on?

Comment: @RyanGadsdon yes using three where for order by, i think this is correct

Comment: Check my update

Answer (score 1):

If you had an example result set the question would make more sense.
Dont know if this is what you want

```
   ORDER BY role, permission, access
```

Example 2:

```
   ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN role= 1 THEN role END ASC/DESC,
   CASE WHEN permission = 2 THEN permission END ASC/DESC,
   CASE WHEN access = 3 THEN access END ASC/DESC
```

The question isnt very clear

Comment: my problem is using `where` or `if` for `order by`

Comment: what is the result?

Comment: for example  `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY CASE WHEN id= 1 THEN id END` is in latest row of result

Comment: Well it would depend what order you put them in the query